# How to send intent from Service to Activity using LocalBroadcastManager?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

We have an app which uses an Android Service.
Sending intents from the service to an activity doesn't work using LocalBroadcastManager. However, the intent is never received by the activity...
(It works using context.sendBroadcast().)

Anyone an idea what's missing here?

**The service:**

```
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(TestService.this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("bar"));

        return START_STICKY;
}
```

**The activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getName();

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Recieved message by BroadcastReciever: " + intent.getAction());
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("bar"));

    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("foo", null, this, TestService.class);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

**The manifest:**

```
<service android:name=".TestService"></service>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(...)`, as well as `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(...)`.

The normal `registerReceiver(...)` and `unregisterReceiver(...)` are for broadcasts sent by `Context#sendBroadcast()` and will not receive those sent by `LocalBroadcastManager#sendBroadcast()`.